# MindMap with TikzTree with seven levels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to recreate a MindMap of 860 Statistical Tests (hypothesis testing) with LaTeX. So far i have found the following script:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
treenode/.style = {draw,ellipse, align=left,
                 top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
root/.style     = {treenode, font=\large, bottom color=white},
env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[  
 level 1/.style={ edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode) to[out=0, in=180] (\tikzchildnode)
        -- (\tikzchildnode)
    },},
level 2/.style={minimum width=200pt, edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode.east) to[out=0, in=180] (\tikzchildnode.south west)
        -- (\tikzchildnode.south east)
    },
    sibling distance=0.6cm},
level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm},
level 2/.append style={level distance=6.5cm},
%edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
%every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped,
     ]

 \node [root] {Algorithm}
[grow=right]
  child [sibling distance=4.0cm] { node{Clustering} 
            child { node  {k-Means}}
            child { node  {k-Medians}}
            child { node  {Expectation Maximisation (EM)}}
            child { node  {Hierarchical Clustering}}
           }
child [sibling distance=4.5cm] { node {Bayesian}
            child { node  {Naive Bayes}}
            child { node  {Gaussian Naive Bayes}}
            child { node  {Multinomial Naive Bayes}}
            child { node  {Averaged One-Depen. Esti. (AODE)}}
            child { node  {Bayesian Belief Network (BBN)}}
            child { node  {Bayesian Network (BN)}}
           }
 child [sibling distance=0.5cm] { node {Decision Tree}
            child { node  {Classification and Regression Tree (CART)}}
            child { node  {Iterative Dichotomiser 3 (ID3)}}
            child { node  {C4.5 and C5.0}} 
            child { node  {Chi-squared Auto.Inte. Det. (CHAID)}}
            child { node  {Decision Stump}}
            child { node  {M5}}
            child { node  {Conditional Decision Trees}}
           } 
 child [sibling distance=5.5cm]{ node {Dimesionality Reduction}
            child { node  {[Principal Component Analysis (PCA)}}
            child { node  {Principal Component Regression (PCR)}}
            child { node  {Partial Least Squares Regression\\(PLSR)}}
            child { node  {Sammon Mapping}}
            child { node  {Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)}}
            child { node  {Projection Pursuit}}
            child { node  {Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)}}
            child { node  {Mixture Discriminant Analysis (MDA)}}
            child { node  {Quadratic Discriminant Analysis (QDA)}}
            child { node  {Flexible Discriminant Analysis (FDA)}}
           }               
 child [sibling distance=5.cm] { node  {Regularisation}
            child { node  {Ridge Regression}}
            child { node  {Least Abs. Shr. and Sel. Ope. (LASSO)}}
            child { node  {Elastic Net}}
            child { node  {Least-Angle Regression (LARS)}}
           };               
\tikzset{
level 1/.style={ edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode) to[out=180, in=0] (\tikzchildnode)
        -- (\tikzchildnode)
    }},
level 2/.style={minimum width=200pt,align=left, edge from parent path={
        (\tikzparentnode) to[out=180, in=0] (\tikzchildnode.south east)
        -- (\tikzchildnode.south west)
    },
    sibling distance=0.6cm},
level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm},
level 2/.append style={level distance=5.5cm},
%edge from parent/.style = {draw, -latex},
%every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
sloped,
     }
  \node [root]{Algorithm}
 [grow=left]
 child [sibling distance=3.1cm]{ node{Deep Learning} 
            child { node  {Deep Boltzmann Machine (DBM)}}
            child { node  {Deep Belief Network (DBN)}}
            child { node  {Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)}}
            child { node  {Stacked Auto-Encoders}}
           }
   child [sibling distance=2.8cm]{ node {Ensamble}
            child { node  {Boosting}}
            child { node  {Bootstrapped Aggregation (Bagging)}}
            child { node  {AdaBoost}}
            child { node  {Stacked Generalization (blending)}}
            child { node  {Gradient Boosting Machines (GBM)}}
            child { node  {Gradient Boosted Regr. Trees (GBRT)}}
            child { node  {Random Forest}}
           }
    child { node{Neural Networks} 
            child { node  {Perceptron}}
            child { node  {Back-Propagation}}
            child { node  {Hopfield Network}}
            child { node  {Radial Basis Function Net. (RBFN)}}
           }
   child[sibling distance=3.9cm] { node {Insatnce Based}
           child { node  {k-Nearest Neighbour(KNN)}}
           child { node  {Learning vector quantization(LVQ)}}             
           child { node  {self-organised map}}
           child { node  {Locally Weighted Learning(LWL)}}
           }
  child[sibling distance=3.2cm] { node {Rule system}
           child { node  {Cubist}}
           child { node  {One Rule (OneR)}}             
           child { node  {Zero Rule (ZeroR)}}
           child { node  {Rep.Inc.Pr2pro. Err. Red. (RIPPER)}}
           }                            
  child [sibling distance=3.3cm]{ node  {Regression}
            child { node  {Linear}}
            child { node  {Ordinary Least Squares}}
            child { node  {Logistic}}
            child { node  {Stepwise}}
            child { node  {Locally Esti.Scatt. Smoo.(LOESS)}}
            child { node  {Multi. Ada. Reg.Splines (MARS)}} 
            };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

But i'm already stucked when adding the 3rd level so that i looks good. I can't even understand the mechanism for the 3rd level so i already know that i will also have probleme for the levels 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Won't you have problems fitting this onto the page or are the following levels much smaller in terms of numbers and size of children?

Comment: The page is a Poster so it’s fine.

Comment: Ah. I tend to forget about posters (even though I finally had to make one a few months ago). They're extremely rare in my discipline.

Answer (score 2):

Some guidance.

The last tutorial in the pgfmanual deals with [mindmaps](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-map), but this is no light meal for a beginner in `Tikz`. I'd rather draw your attention to [Ch.21 Making trees grow](https://tikz.dev/tikz-trees), and, if needed, to the [Trees library](https://tikz.dev/library-trees). The following is guided by Ch. 21.

I'm showing you:

- a Right-node, growing a tree to the right
- same for a Left node
- and finally draw another one inbetween (which you could have placed separately beforehand at (0,0) for example)

As long as you manage to follow the syntax `child{` `node {text}` `}` you are on your way; frequently compiling helps stopping errors (often the braces) from propagating.

As you can see, in principle you can expand to (m)any level(s). But quickly you run into positioning problems. That's where level specific formats/styles come into play, which allow you to position members of a certain child-level. See Ch- 21.4.

[image: sibblings]

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ a tree to the right ~~~~~~
    \node (R) at (2,0) {root-R} [grow=right]
        child{node {1-1}
            child{node {2-1}}
            child{node {2-2}
                child{node {3-1}}
                child{node {3-2}
                }% closes 3-2
            }% closes 2-2
        }% closes 1-1
        child{node {1-2}
            child{node {2-2}}
        }
        ; 

    % ~~~ a tree to the left ~~~~~~ 
    \node (L) at (-2,0) {root-L} [grow=left]
        child{node {1-1}}
        child{node {1-2}}
        ; 

    % ~~~ let's draw sth. inbetween ~~~~
    \draw (L) -- node[fill=white,draw=blue] {roots root} (R);   
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code you posted is basically doing the same. Some positioning control is assigned to some children, lots of appearance related styles are summarized in the `\tikzset{}` statements.

I suggest to start small, i.e. "naked in terms of text apearance and layout embellishment", and introduce level after level, step-by-step.

Comment: I will try again. If i succeed i will post the result. If i don’t succeed i won’t post anything…

Comment: @VincentISOZ, I suggest, should you not succeed, to post anyway, because you most likely will have introduced changes anyway.

Comment: @VincentISOZ I'd second the above. By all means post again if you get stuck. I also agree about avoiding the `mindmaps` library. It's really not easy to use and it doesn't lend itself to the style of most mind maps. I only use it when I want the bubble style nodes etc.